# jqm 1.2 listview - dynamically append new <li> element to top

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, append, splice

does anyone know a method to append a new element to the top of a listview ?

The normal method of append adds the element to the end of a listview.

Maybe there is a method to (reverse / append / reverse) or a equivalent to the javascript array methods? As example: splice(0,0,"topelement")?

The possibility to add elements to the top of a view and respective sort / reverse functions would be highly recommened for many database oriented apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `prepand` instead of `append`

this will get your work done

Comment: thank you - thas was a flash answer! I try to use http://api.jquery.com/prepend/.